# Is there a way to see all of the Google Photos Creations?

Tags: google-photos

The Google Photos Creations used to be grouped under *Auto Awesome*. Since the re-branding, Auto Awesome doesn't exist anymore. Is there way to see these things without manually going through all of the photos or albums?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see the Creations you've saved...

1. Go to the "[Search](https://photos.google.com/search)" page
2. Scroll to the bottom and click "[Creations](https://photos.google.com/search/_taa_)"
   [image: Types]

To see the Creations the Assistant has suggested, but which you didn't save...

1. Go to the "[Assistant](https://photos.google.com/assistant)" page
   [image: Assistant link]
2. Scroll to the bottom and click "[VIEW UNSAVED CREATIONS](https://photos.google.com/unsaved)"
   [image: VIEW UNSAVED CREATIONS]

(I don't know if this latter holds on to Creations that you've explicitly dismissed/deleted.)